# "tassels on the four corners of your garment"

Tags: deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 22:12 (NASB)

> “You shall make yourself **tassels on the four corners of your garment** with which you cover yourself.

What does this represent?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/446/arbaa-mi-yodeya/18348#18348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deuteronomy 22:12

> “You shall make yourself tassels on the four corners of your garment with which you cover yourself.

[image]
[image]

An elaborated description is in Numbers 15:

> 37The Lord said to Moses, 38“Speak to the Israelites and say to them: ‘Throughout the generations to come you are to make **tassels** on the corners of your garments, with a **blue** cord on each tassel. 39You will have these tassels to look at and so you will remember all the commands of the Lord, that you may obey them and not prostitute yourselves by chasing after the lusts of your own hearts and eyes. 40Then you will remember to **obey all my commands** and will be consecrated to your God. 41I am the Lord your God, who brought you out of Egypt to be your God. I am the Lord your God.’ ”

The tassels are also called tsitsit. They serve as a reminder for the wearer to obey God's commands.